# GCC cross compile error linking libraries from same directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, raspberry-pi, ld

I am building an application for the Raspberry Pi using the userland libraries (https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland).  I have correctly setup a GCC cross compiler, correctly compiled the userland libraries and have a working Makefile for my application.  When I add in references to the userland libraries and update the Makefile to point to the lib directory only a few of the libraries are found and I get errors that LD can't find other libraries which are in the same directory.

Here is a link to a an annotated pic of the output, LD correctly finds libmmal but can't find libmmal_vc_client which is in the same library directory.

http://protological.com/browser/files/link_libraries_error.png

Why is LD not finding the libmmal_vc_client lib but finding the libmmal lib?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with lots of external libraries, it appears that I must specify each library with a -l option in the Makefile.  For others looking for how to build against raspberry pi userland for the camera here are the libaries:

-lmmal_core -lmmal -l mmal_util -lvcos -lcontainers -lbcm_host -lmmal_vc_client -lmmal_components -lvchiq_arm